# The number of ways you could pay 1997 using decimal currency of $1$,$10$,$100$,$1000$ .

Tags: combinatorics, summation

[image: This is the question's text.]

The way I did it is as follows:

To pay $1997$, one could pay :$1900$, $90$ and $7$.

There is only one way to pay $7$, using notes of value of $1$.

There are $10$ ways of paying $90$, using $1$ or $10$ notes.

Now, to work out how many ways we could pay 1900 using $1000$, $100$, $10$ and $1$:

Suppose we pay $1900$ using $n$ $1000$ notes, $m$ $100$ notes, $r$ $10$ notes and $k$ $1$ notes.

So, we write:
$$1000n + 100m + 10r + k = 1900$$

$n$ could take any value between $0$ and $1$

$m$ could take any value between $0$ and $19-10n$

$r$ could take any value between $0$ and $190 - 100n - 10m$ at

Once the value of $r$ is decided, then the value of $k$ is automatically decided.

Then the Total number of ways of paying $1900$ is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{n=1}\sum_{m=0}^{m = 19-10n}(191 - 100n - 10m)$$

Which simplifies to:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{n=1}(1920 - 1960n + 500n^2)$$

Leading to:

$$2380$$

So in total, we've got $1$ way to pay $7$, $10$ ways to pay $90$ and $2380$ to pay $1900$.

So, the total number of ways is $$2380*10*1 = 23800$$

Is is this the right approach?

Thanks,

Comment: No. The coefficient of $x^{1997}$ in the Taylor series of $$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^{10})(1-x^{100})(1-x^{1000})}$$ at the origin is $\color{red}{2650}$.

Comment: I see. I am sorry, but I am new to this. how's that related?

Comment: Such coefficient is exacly the number of solutions of $a+10b+100c+1000d=1997$ with $(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{N}^4$, since $$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots,\qquad \frac{1}{1-x^{10}}=1+x^{10}+x^{20}+x^{30}+\ldots $$ and so on.

Comment: Your options in paying the 90 pippins overlap the options in paying the 1900.

Comment: Ohh right. I see now.  cheers

Comment: Would it be useful if I use the same method but on $$1000n + 100m + 10r + k = 1997$$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a problem from the 1997 British Mathematical Olympiad (https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/home/bmo1-1997.pdf) - as such it seems reasonable to *not* use generating functions (as Jack D'Aurizio has in his comment), and to come up with a solution that requires only hand computation.  So let's try to adapt your approach.

In a solution to $1000n + 100m + 10r + k = 1997$ in positive integers:

- $n$ is 0 or 1
- $m$ is between $0$ and $19 - 10n$
- $r$ is between $0$ and $199 - 100n - 10m$ (so there are $200 - 100n - 10m$ possible values).   **This is the error in your original solution** - once $n$ and $m$ are determined we haver $1000n + 100m$ pippins, so the amount remaining to be allocated is $(1997 - 1000n - 100m)/10$.
- $k$ is fixed once $n, m, r$ are determined.

So you are looking for

$$\sum_{n=0}^1 \sum_{m=0}^{19 - 10n} (200 - 100n - 10m) $$

and notice that this differs from your double sum only by replacing $191$ with $200$.  Now it's just computation.

Explicitly expanding the outer sum into the $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ terms gives

$$ \sum_{m=0}^{19} (200 - 10m) + \sum_{m=0}^{9} (100-10m) $$.

By the usual formulas for the sum of arithmetic progressions, this is

$$ {20 \over 2} (10+200) + {10 \over 2} (10+100) = (10)(210) + (5)(110) = 2100 + 550 = 2650. $$